# How to trigger autocomplete on character - Ace Editor

Tags: ace-editor

How can I do the following with the Ace Editor.

1. User types the '@' character
2. Autocomplete pops up
3. User makes a selection from the dropdown
4. The '@' gets removed now that the selection has been made

I basically want the @ as a trigger for the autocomplete, but I don't want it hanging around after.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
addAutoComplete() {
    var me = this;
    ace.require('./config').loadModule('ace/ext/language_tools', () => {
        this.aceEditor.setOptions({
            enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
            enableSnippets: true,
            enableLiveAutocompletion: false
        });
        me.include = /[a-z.]/i;
        this.aceEditor.on('change', (obj, editor) => {
            switch (obj.action) {
                case 'insert':
                    let lines = obj.lines;
                    let char = lines[0];
                    if ((lines.length === 1) && (char.length === 1) && me.include.test(char)) {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            me.aceEditor.commands.byName.startAutocomplete.exec(me.aceEditor);
                        }, 50);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

that's the demo. works fine

Comment: Finally, a working solution! `aceEditor.commands.byName.startAutocomplete.exec(aceEditor);` does the trick for me.

Comment: What's the need for the timeout though?

Answer (score 1):

We can bind the '@' keyword and trigger the autocomplete:

```
 editor.commands.addCommand({
        name: "myCommand",
        bindKey: { win: "@", mac: "@" },
        exec: function (editor) {
              autocomplete();
        }
 });

  autocomplete: function () {
        staticWordCompleter = {
            var getWordList = function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback, isRHSEditor) {
            var wordList = []; // add your words to this list

            callback(null, wordList.map(function(word) {
            return {
                 caption: word,
                value: word
            };
   }));
  editor.completers = [staticWordCompleter];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above approaches worked for me. I ended up rolling my own autocomplete/autosuggest for this to work. It's hard to contrive an example but in short the steps are:

1. Capture the onChange of the editor
2. If the editor action meets the criteria (i.e. the @ symbol is pressed), display a box at the cursor position. This can be done by setting the box to position absolute, and setting the top/left attributes:

```
const {row, column} = window.editor.getCursorPosition();
const {pageX, pageY} = window.editor.renderer.textToScreenCoordinates(row, column)
const autosuggest = document.getElementById("ELEMENT_NAME")
autosuggest.style.left = pageX
autosuggest.style.top = pageY
```

3. Add commands to disable/redirect any actions such as the arrow keys/enter key, and re-enable when a selection is made.

```
function disableEnterKeyInEditor() {
    editor.commands.addCommand(commmand_enter);
}

function enableEnterKeyInEditor() {
    editor.commands.removeCommands(commmand_enter);
}

command_enter = {
    name: "enterKeyPressedCommand",
    bindKey: {win: "Enter", mac: "Enter"},
    exec: function (editor) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

This was much easier than working with ace's autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of ace you can use `triggerCharacters`

Below code will trigger autocomplete popup on `@`

```js
    const completer = {
        getCompletions: function (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
            
            callback(
                null,
                autoCompletes.map((word) => ({ value: word, score: 1000, meta: "components" }))
            );
        },
        triggerCharacters: ["@"],
    };
```

Full Example [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajnandan/jcwqpvgk/6/)

Answer (score -1):

You can check with below code:

```
var getWordList = function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback, isRHSEditor) {
    var wordList = [];
    if(prefix === '@') {
        wordList.push('add you're name list here');
    }
    callback(null, wordList.map(function(word) {
        return {
            caption: word,
            value: word
        };
    }));
}
```